# How do I check a set of numbers in different columns against numbers in different columns

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, conditional-formatting, google-sheets-circular-references

I am trying to make a Lotto checklist. I have my own numbers in 6 columns A2:F2, and I have typed the winning numbers in H2:M2, 6 columns also. Now I want to check if my numbers in A2:F2 have any one or more of the numbers present in the winning numbers in H2:M2. And if there is a match, highlight the matched cell in red background and white text.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule for the range `A2:F2`:

```
=countif($H2:$M2, A2)
```

Comment: Thanks. The formula worked. it got the two matched numbers in A2:F2.  but I forgot to mention that  H2:M2 has 1000 rows, my bad.

Comment: `H2:M2` is a one-row range. It is possible to make a formula that checks `A2:F2` against every row separately in the 999-row range `H2:M1000`, but that is a different question. Please do not present new requirements after you have received an answer. Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.

Comment: Sorry for that.  I will correct my question and ask a new  question instead. Thanks!